# When the width is changing with regards to window size, how do I align elements that in separate divs?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I have a search input and a result element. Both are in separate divs/containers but I need them to align when the window size changes. I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it than with Javascript.

One window size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiQtY.png
A smaller window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgj4I.png

I'm using this: http://getuikit.com/docs/utility.html and I'm liking it but with regards to responsive design I'm clearly doing something wrong. Shouldn't be this hard to get two elements to align regardless of screen width. Any suggestions?

My HTML

```
    <div class="header-section">
    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-text-center">
        <h1 class="uk-h1" id="head1">Search</h1>
        <h1 class="uk-h1" id="head2">Lab</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="input-section">
    <div class ="uk-container uk-container-center uk-text-center">
        <form id="search-form" class="uk-form">
            <input id="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Bing Engine ">
            <button id="search-btn" class="uk-button uk-button-primary" type="button">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="results-section">
    <div id="results-container" class="uk-container uk-container-center uk-width-1-2">
        <div class="result">
            <a class="result-title" href="#">Bhutan travel advice</a>
            <div class="result-url">https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/bhutan</div>
            <p class="result-summary">Latest travel advice for Bhutan including safety and security, entry requirements, travel warnings and health.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It felt quite clean to me.

My CSS: http://pastebin.com/4kkpe8cq

Comment: Your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/cgnmQ/

Comment: How do you want them to be aligned?

Comment: Just so the start of the result is at the start of the bar.

Comment: The fiddle doesn't match your screen shots. If you want the input box to be on the same horizontal position as the result, then the fiddle already does that!

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
@media(min-width:800px) {
   // your CSS for a small width
}
```

Comment: OP says: "I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do it than with Javascript."